# CLion remote development - how to sync vcpkg packages?

Tags: cmake, clion, vcpkg

I have a `cmake` project that uses `vcpkg` (I added `vcpkg` as a `submodule` under my repo and configured `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to point to the `vcpkg.cmake`).

Now I configured CLion to connect over `ssh` and build **remotely** on a different machine, but I am not sure how I can go about telling it to **sync my vcpkg folder** which is outside of the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`.

I tried also to put the `vcpkg` `submodule` in `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` (even though I would like to keep it separate) and this works, it gets synced.

I was thinking also if there is some way to control where CLion does the `sync` on the remote machine and I could just put `vcpkg` there myself (relative to the sync path) and install the needed packages, but I did not find this option either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found how to set the remote for my ssh connection path:

```
File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment
```

So I can go myself on the remote machine, clone `vcpkg` relatively to the `Deployment` path and install all packages.

This works well enough, I just need to make remember to install any new packages in both places.

**EDIT:**
I found also a completely **automated solution**:
From the same CLion `Deployment` settings, I can actually add multiple `mappings` so I can add an extra folder sync for my out of source `vcpkg`.

At the end, I am thinking that it will be a waste for CLion to keep the whole `vcpkg` with all the installed packages automatically in sync when I can just sync it myself once in a blue moon when I install a new package.
I am not sure how expensive it would be for CLion to monitor such a big folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a path to CMAKE params to tell it where vcpkg is installed on the remote host, something like this:

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```